# LuaJit FFI and hiding C implementation details

Tags: scripting, lua, luajit

I would like to extend an application using LuaJit FFI. Having seen http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html this is surprisingly easy when comparing this to the Lua C API. So far so good. However I do not plainly want to wrap C functions but provide a higher level API to users writing scripts for the application. Especially I do not want users to be able to access "primitives", i.e. the `ffi.*` namespace. Is this possible or will that ffi namespace be available to user's Lua scripts?

On the issue of Sandboxing Lua I found http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes which is not talking about FFI though.

Furthermore, the plan I have described above is assuming that the introduction of abstraction layers happens on the lua side of code. Is this an advisable approach or would you rather abstract functionality on the statically compiled code (on the C-side)?

Answer (score 2):

when you ask if "will that ffi namespace be available to user's Lua scripts?", do you care because of ease of programming, to make it harder to make a mistake, or to protect against deliberate malicious attacks?

if the last (security), then yes, you have to check about sandboxes.  it's not hard to do a reasonable one, but a real tight one is tricky.

if the others (easy to use, hard to break), then just be sure that the exported module contains only the high-level functions you want others to use.  The easiest way is to make your internal functions in local variables, and put only the "exported" functions in the table that will become your module.  (hint: don't use the module() function)